# Making pizza toppings stay intact without using cheese

Tags: substitutions, cheese, pizza, ingredient-selection

I am going to be following this recipe to make my pizza dough
https://tasty.co/recipe/2-ingredient-dough-pizza

However, I have just realised we ran out of cheese. I have processed cheese slices but I don't think that would taste good on the pizza. They're only good for cheese toasties.

How can I make sure my pizza toppings stay intact on the pizza base? Once I made a pizza without cheese and everything just fell everywhere when I start cutting into the pizza. Is there an easy alternative to cheese, or a tip to make the ingredients stick together?

Comment: The function of cheese in pizza is NOT to keep the toppings in place. Try making the edges higher so they better contain the sauce and toppings, and use less sauce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pizza is made with mozzarella for taste, not as glue,
actually it acts as/has the same role as glue basically.
The effect is achieved thanks to its **texture** which leads condiments to *sink/fall into* it and **greasiness** which acts as a *glue*.

Without cheese you can try to:

1. don't load excessively with dressing
2. as dressing, use small cut, such as small cut of vegetables, of wurstel, etc
3. use a little of olive oil on top

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding some sauce on top of the toppings, just a light layer to hold things in place.

It'll brown a bit and harden slightly, which might add enough firmness to keep things from sliding off.

The cheese normally does this, plus it's "sticky" and stretchy, so it keeps all the ingredients in one place, more-or-less.

Answer (score 2):

You can chop your toppings to be smaller and mix them into your sauce. And use that mixture as your topping.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a "stuffed" type of pizza, a thick crust with sauce and toppings, and another layer of crust on the top.

Or, you could make a Sicilian style pizza, with very thick doughey crust. Then, push the ingredients down into the crust so that they are embedded a bit. You could also then cover these ingredients with sauce to seal them in place.

But really, if you are making pizza and you don't have any cheese - why not just make something else for dinner?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your toppings need to be dehydrated so no water can pour down to easen your dough.
2. Sprinkle some olive oil on your pizza, the heat will produce a vapor that protects your toppings similar to cheese. If you have a stove with more than 230°C then use avocado oil.